# Can't open file '/var/www/svn/repos/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied on RapidSVN

Tags: 13.04, permissions, svn

I tried to commit my modified file on SVN (RapidSVN). I got the following error:

```
Error while performing action: Commit failed (details follow): 
Can't open file '/var/www/svn/repos/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

Can anyone help in solving this? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Good Question Supravat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you have this file `/var/www/svn/repos/db/txn-current-lock` on your machine. Have you checked whether it `exists on your system or not`. How can you give permission on files which does not belong to your system.

It might be issue which `server admin should take care of`.He should give proper permission to files.Ask them.

Check this http://www.jamison.org/2011/09/13/fixing-the-svn-txn-current-lock-permission-denied-error-in-subversion/

Comment: point ta gift korchi..Upvote from me

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the command(s) as root.

1. Open the terminal
2. Run the following command:

> sudo su

3 . Then run the commands you want.

The following commands that you execute will get run as root, and hopefully you will get permission access the '/var/www/svn/repos/db/txn-current-lock' file.

Comment: When I try to get permission through terminal, getting the following error
`root@supravat:/# sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/svn/repos/*
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
root@supravat:/# `

Comment: Run "sudo su". Then just run the command that you want, without sudo. Just: chmod 777 -R /var/www/svn/repos/*

Comment: The above command is run but getting error still.

Comment: Using sudo for this is not a fix but more of a hammer approach.